# Merge the files with the same file name in Perl

Tags: perl, file-io, fastq

I currently got a problem on merging the files in Perl.
There are two directories/folders, which contain the same name and extension files in pairs.
For example, in folder 1, I have files 1.fastq, 2.fastq,....,10.fastq.
In folder 2, I have the exactly same file names 1.fastq, 2.fastq,....,10.fastq, but they contain different information.
I want to merge the files with the same name, in the beginning I tried the cat command

```
$ cat 1.fastq 1.fastq > 1.fastq
```

However if there are too many files, for example 1000+, I will need to do it 1000+ times.
How can I do it automatically with the perl command?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think it's easier if you write a shell script rather than opening and closing files with Perl.

Answer (score 6):

Perl based solution will be like below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$source_dir = "./source";
$dest_dir   = "./dest";
opendir ($source, $source_dir);
@source_files = readdir $source;
foreach $each_file (@source_files){
    if($each !~ /^(\.|\.\.)$/) {
        open $file_h , "< $source_dir/$each_file";
        @contents = <$file_h>;
        open $dest_file, ">>$dest_dir/$each_file";
        print $dest_file @contents;
        @contents =();
     }
}
```

You can also do this using Shell script also. A typical shell script will be like below.

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
source='./source'
dest='./dest'
for file in `ls $source`
do
if [ -e $dest/$file ] 
then 
    cat $source/$file $dest/$file >> $dest/$file."unique_name"
    rm $dest/$file
    mv $dest/$file."unique_name" $dest/$file
else
    cp $source/$file $dest/$file
fi
done
```

You can not use input file as output with cat.

```
$ cat 1.fastq 1.fastq > 1.fastq
```

This will lead you error saying "`input file is output file`".